# SQL Reporting Services Report Version Compare

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've inherited a headache!  I have two SQL Reporting Services servers.  One is a production server, the other is a test server.  I know for a fact that some of the reports were deployed directly to production.  I know for a fact that some reports are out of sync, meaning the version on Test isn't the same as the version on Prod and vice-versa.
I want to pull all of the rdl files down from the servers and just run a diff against them to see which reports are different.  Does anybody know of a way to pull the rdl files down or have a better suggestion about how to compare these two sets of reports?  They number over 100 so I'm trying to avoid a one at a time approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as the files are basically generated on the fly by the SQL Server.

You can, however, use the following tool to extract the RDL files from the SQL Server:
[RS Scripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62)

I hope this helps.